# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask, firebaseui

I am creating my application and I need to fill the recyclerview and then scroll to the desired item. To do this, I used AsyncTask, but the problem is that scrollToPosition () does not work. Maybe someone will tell me what I am doing wrong, since this is my first time working with AsyncTask and I do not understand what my mistake is.

```
public class SomeUserProfileFragment extends Fragment {

 private void loadUserPosts() {
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

        new SetFirebaseRecyclerAdapter().execute();
    }

 class SetFirebaseRecyclerAdapter extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TestPosts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TestPosts>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid), TestPosts.class)
                    .build();

            mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
            mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
      

  mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        adapter = new TestPostsAdapter(options, mContext);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(1);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: **this is my first time working with AsyncTask** - buddy, AsyncTask is deprecated. There should be no "first time working with AsyncTask in 2021.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo no, I don't have any errors.The problem is, the scrolltoposition does absolutely nothing. Whatever argument I use RecyclerView stands still

Comment: @dominicoder it is deprecated from android 11 but I'm using android 10

Comment: @lin - the fact that you're using an older version of Android is irrelevant. You should not be using deprecated APIs when there are better alternatives. You're wasting time learning / using a class that is no longer used and will just have to be refactored or replaced later anyway. Just start with something modern and relevant _now_.